# two products, different arrivals times, Anylogic

Tags: product, anylogic

I have two products (agent A,B) with different arrivals times (rate time). The two products are processed by the same machine M1 with two different times for each product. How can I do in Anylogic?

Answer (score 1):

There is nearly no limit to the number of possible ways to develop a model.  You are asking for a really introductory level system, so I would recommend you go through the AnyLogic in 3 days book, if you have not already done so.

Given how simple your described system is, I would just do the following:

1. Create an agent class of "Product".  Add a parameter to that class.  I used an integer iProductType to mark 0 for A and 1 for B.  You could use strings or option lists as well.
2. Create 2 populations - one for A and one for B, pass in the parameter of 0 for A and 1 for B.
3. Add 2 source blocks, one for each of the products.  Each block has its own rates.  In the Advanced section, this is where you can set the population.
4. Connect 2 source blocks to the a delay block.  In the delay block, you can call a function an delay based on if agent.iProductType == 0 or agent.iProductType == 1.

A picture of what the function may look like is below.
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!